# How to implement Oauth 2.0 Client that handles storing refreshToken in DB?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-api-java-client, google-oauth

So, in my case, I will use Gmail API to fetch email from my backend server. After reading about oauth 2.0 mechanism, it seems like in order to gain access when there is no user online, we use 'offline' accessType. So user should authorize once in the beginning, and the rest process will give `accessToken` and `refreshToken` to my backend server.

Looking at google oauth api client sampe, I think they don't give any flexibility on how to store and load the `refreshToken`. Instead, they serve full solution by storing that `refreshToken` in file, which is not what I want.
Is there any java oauth 2.0 client library that gives this flexibility (store and load `refreshToken`)?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the official [OAuth 2 page](http://oauth.net/2/). There are lists of OAuth 2 client frameworks to choose from.

And I would not store Access Tokens as it is provided by the Service Provider and it can expire. If the access token expires, I would send a grant request to refresh the token.

Comment: Hi, please have take a look at this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

It actually recommends to store the refreshToken for future use.

Comment: That is specific to Google. It's better to stick to the OAuth 2 API instead, which Google has implemented.

Comment: I am sorry, but as far as I understand, the refreshToken is exists for renewing accessToken. So, by storing that refreshToken, we can actually handle the accessToken expiration by requesting it again to resource-server.

Comment: Refresh token can be used to request another access token once it expires so I would never store it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the backend API server you are planning to use. You can use WSO2 IS which internally has the OAuth2 implementation.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/OpenID+Connect+with+the+WSO2+Identity+Server+and+WSO2+OAuth2+Playground

They expose restful-webservices and security can be implemented

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your answer. So what I want is java-based oauth 2.0 client library that can give me flexibility to store and load the refreshToken from the oauth-server.

Comment: The security implementation is exposed as restful web-services, you can always go ahead and use java to consume the same. With an IDP in between, you will have loose coupling, and modularity.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @YagneshAgola : the link is for WSO2 IS documentation. it is a step by step guide to implement the and place security encapsulating your application and securing the same.